# Derivation of holomorphic periods

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose you are given a holomorphic function $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i$ as a power series. How can you characterize the set of all constants $\sigma$ such that $f(x + \sigma) = f(x)$?

Example:

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{i!}x^i \rightarrow \sigma =  \lbrace 2i\pi K \rbrace \in \mathbb{N}$$

other example:

$$ f(x) = 10x + 1, \sigma = \lbrace 0 \rbrace $$

Is there an algorithm for manipulating $a_i$ to directly conclude this?

Comment: Specifying every coefficient of a power series is an infinite amount of information, so I don't really understand what kind of answer you're looking for. Here's an example: let $a_i = \frac{B_i}{i!}$ where $B_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Bell number (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number). What are the periods? I claim that there are some, but I have no idea how you would see this from any kind of direct inspection of the coefficients.

Comment: I'm looking for an operator or algorithm that would take advantage of this